# Latex table with Multirow

Tags: tables, multicol, multirow

I've been struggling with this for a while.

1.) I want the 2.5 and 97.5 to appear distinctly from the "Percentile" label but still in the same cell.

2.) I want the 2.5 to appear centered around the "P" in "Percentile and I want the 97.5 to appear centered around the last e in "percentile"

3.) the 0.05 and 0.57 should appear directly below the 2.5 and 97.5 respectively (in their new positions)

Baz

```
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{tabular}{l|cc}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Steepener Sharpe Ratio Estimation Results} \\
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Estimate} }  &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Percentile}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.5} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{97.5} \\
\cline{2-3} 
TNA & 0.05 & 0.57 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Please provide a compilable Minimum Working Example as that it is much more useful than a mere fragment of code. May I ask why you want to do this? That is, why do you want things centered on the first and last letter of the column header? I ask because I don't think this will be straightforward at all. You could do it using TiKZ, for example, but you are trying to do something with tabular which is not really what tabular is intended to do. That is, you are not really trying to typeset a table but something effectively closer to a graphic.

Comment: I have flexibility is the formatting so I'm happy to go with a simpler layout that displays the same data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you take the following steps:

- Use a `table` environment, with a `\caption` that's distinct from the tabular material itself. The caption can be placed either above or below the tabular material. In the example below I use `\caption*` -- a macro provided by the `caption` package -- to create an *unnumbered* table float. (If you want a "regular", i.e., numbered table float, use `\caption` instead of `\caption*`.)
- Use the line-drawing commands of the `booktabs` package to get *well-spaced horizontal lines*.
- *Don't use vertical lines* -- they merely add *visual clutter*. (If you don't believe me, try to create a few tables for yourself, first with vertical lines and then without. Ask yourself critically if *any* of the vertical lines in any of your tables truly add visual clarity.)

The following screenshot shows both your current table as well as the one I suggest.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}          % for old code
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}  % for new code
\begin{document}

before:
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|cc}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Steepener Sharpe Ratio Estimation Results} \\
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Estimate} }  &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Percentile}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.5} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{97.5} \\
\cline{2-3} 
TNA & 0.05 & 0.57 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\bigskip
new:
\begin{table}[h!] % "[h!]" location specifier just for this example
\caption*{Steepener Sharpe Ratio Estimation Results}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
Estimate & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Percentile} \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
& 2.5 & 97.5 \\
\midrule
TNA & 0.05 & 0.57 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the \cmidrule line lighter, with lighter meaning thinner or greysh?

Comment: @Mengops - Absolutely. The default value of `\cmidrulewidth` is `0.03em`. To change it to, say, `0.02em`, you'd issue the command `\setlength\cmidrulewidth{0.02em}`.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but after compiling, nothing changes. may it be due to the fact that I'm using a report documentclass? If so how can I solve it?

Comment: @Mengops - I'm afraid a term such as "nothing changes" is not very informative. I suggest you post a *new query*, in which you state what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 4):

May be this would do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
{\centering
Steepener Sharpe Ratio Estimation Results

\begin{tabular}{l|cc}
%\hline
%\multicolumn{3}{c}{Steepener Sharpe Ratio Estimation Results} \\
\cline{1-3}
\multirow{2}{*}{Estimate}  &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Percentile} \\
 &  2.5 &  97.5 \\
\cline{2-3}
TNA & 0.05 & 0.57 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\par
}
\end{document}
```

[image]